# Добавить [sqlite3] синонимом к [sqlite]

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

[sqlite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite) - это название СУБД, а [sqlite3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3) - это единственная используемая на данный момент версия этой СБУД.

Может эти 2 тега объединить в один ([sqlite3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3) сделать синонимом [sqlite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite))?

Сам я этого сделать не могу, так как у меня для этого сильно мало репутации.

Comment: На английском SO это синонимы. Думаю, стоит объединить, как и у них.

Comment: А почему основной с версией?

Comment: наоборот "sqlite3 сделать синонимом"

Comment: @СабирИсламов лучше голосованием решить)

Answer (score 18):

Основной сделать метку [sqlite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite).

Answer (score -3):

Основной сделать метку [sqlite3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3).

Answer (score -5):

Оставить две отдельные метки. Если сейчас актуальна только одна версия sqlite, это не значит что не будет момента, когда будут параллельно использоваться две версии, например sqlite3 и sqlite4, и возникнет необходимость различать вопросы по версиям.

Comment: Так почти про каждую метку сказать можно. Всё же незачем им всем добавлять номера версий без необходимости